Whats the meaning of Tirmidhi 1547
The hadith:

Abu Umamah, and other than him from the Companions of the Prophet (ﷺ), narrated that the Prophet (ﷺ) said:
"Any Muslim man who frees a Muslim man, then it is his salvation from the Fire - each of his limbs suffices for a limb of himself. And any Muslim man that frees two Muslim women, then are his salvation from the Fire - each of their limbs suffices for a limb of himself. And any Muslim woman that frees a Muslim woman, then she is her salvation from the Fire - each of her limb suffices for a limb of herself."

My question is, whats the reason that freeing 2 Muslim female slaves is equivalent to 1 male if a man frees them, but for a Muslim woman freeing 1 Muslim female is enough?

Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].

Reason is a free man is more beneficial to society then free woman. In those society 1400 years ago A free slave woman, will either had to be married to someone or find a way to survive on her own or she had to be taken care by govt. If I am not wrong if a slave woman is freed then she becomes haram for her master, so he is not responsible for her (maybe I am wrong on the last sentence).
Also, free man is beneficial cuz he can and most definitely help in economy by working or doing business, also, most likely he would fight wars etc.
Lastly, this is what prophet peace and blessings be upon him said, and we as Muslim accept it. Allah says in the quran, the prophet doesn't say anything from on his will.
These are my opinions, not of any muslim scholars. So, they are not authoritive. If I said something wrong may Allah forgive me.

Wait but a woman is given the reward if she frees a slave woman but the man is given the same reward if he frees 2 slave women

Some scholars believe that freeing female slaves is preferable because when a female slave is freed, any children she has will automatically be free, regardless of whether she marries a free man or another slave:

قال القاضي عياض: واختَلَف العلماء أيما أفضل، عتق الإناث، أم عتق الذكور؟ فقال بعضهم: الإناث أفضل؛ لأنها إذا عَتَقَت كان ولدها حرًّا، سواء تزوجها حرّ، أو عبدٌ


Qadi Iyad said: Scholars have differed on which is better: freeing female slaves or freeing male slaves. Some said freeing females is better because when she is freed, her children are free whether she marries a free man or a slave.

Other scholars argue that freeing male slaves is better:

وقال آخرون: عتق الذكور أفضل؛ لهذا الحديث، ولما في الذَّكر من المعاني العامة المنفعة التي لا توجد في الإنات، من الشهادة، والقضاء، والجهاد، وغير ذلك، مما يختص بالرجال، إما شرعًا، وإما عادةً، ولأن من الإماء من لا ترغب في العتق، وتَضِيع به، بخلاف العبيد


Others said that freeing male slaves is better, based on this hadith and because males have benefits that females do not, such as serving as witnesses, judges, and in jihad, among other roles specific to men by law or custom. Additionally, some female slaves may not want to be freed and might suffer as a result, unlike male slaves.

Al-Baḥr al-Muḥīṭ al-Thajjāj fī Sharḥ Ṣaḥīḥ al-Imām Muslim ibn al-Ḥajjāj 26/586
